# Collect to map skipping null values

Tags: kotlin

How to collect to Map from List where null values are excluded/skipped?

This code doesn't skip null values:

```
val map = listOf(Pair("a", 1), Pair("b", null), Pair("c", 3), Pair("d", null))
    .associateBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
println(map)
```

Workaround solution. But collects into mutable map:

```
val map2 = listOf(Pair("a", 1), Pair("b", null), Pair("c", 3), Pair("d", null))
    .mapNotNull {
        if (it.second != null) it else null
    }.toMap()    
println(map2)
```

So is there more convenient way to do this? Also I want to get `Map<String, Int>` type, not `Map<String, Int?>`

Comment: `mapNotNull` doesn't make sense here because it checks if `Pair` is not `null`

Comment: @pwolaq That isn't true, if you look at the lambda passed to `mapNotNull`.

Comment: What do you mean by "collects into mutable map"? `toMap` returns a `Map`, not a `MutableMap`.

Comment: @Moira you are right, I didn't look up reference and I though that `mapNotNull` simply skips `null` values and applies the transform on the remaining ones

Comment: There exists also a feature request to add it to the standard library: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14041/associateByNotNull The main holdup is that there would be a lot of functions that need to be added for all the different variants and receiver types.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Actually, a slight change to pwolaq's answer guarantees that the second item is non-nullable:

```
val map = listOf(Pair("a", 1), Pair("b", null), Pair("c", 3), Pair("d", null))
    .mapNotNull { p -> p.second?.let { Pair(p.first, it) } }
    .toMap()
println(map)
```

This will give you a `Map<String, Int>`, since `mapNotNull` ignores anything that maps to `null`, and using `let` with the safe call operator `?.` returns null if its receiver (`p.second`) is `null`.

This is basically what you stated in your question, made shorter with `let`.

Answer (score 12):

Since Kotlin 1.6, there is also a stable [buildMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-map.html) function that can be used to write custom helper functions that are performant without sacrificing readability:

```
fun <T, K : Any, V : Any> Iterable<T>.associateByNotNull(
    keySelector: (T) -> K?,
    valueTransform: (T) -> V?,
): Map<K, V> = buildMap {
    for (item in this@associateByNotNull) {
        val key = keySelector(item) ?: continue
        val value = valueTransform(item) ?: continue
        this[key] = value
    }
}
```

Note that writing this as a "low-level" for loop eliminates the need for the creation of intermediate collections.

Comment: This is 100% the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Comment: It may be also `inline` as other associate functions in stdlib.

Answer (score 9):

You want to filter out `null` values, then you should use `filter` method:

```
val map = listOf(Pair("a", 1), Pair("b", null), Pair("c", 3), Pair("d", null))
    .filter { it.second != null }
    .toMap()
println(map)
```

Comment: What if use toMap() instead of associateBy()? At least Java-generated code is shorter. associateBy() generates excess Pairs but we already have them.

Comment: Also your code returns Map with nullable type i.e. not `Map<String, Int>` but `Map<String, Int?>`

Comment: @EldarAgalarov you would have to cast the values yourself if you want to have non nullable types here

Answer (score 2):

A more readable solution might be using the associateBy function with the double bang expression (!!):

```
val map: Map<String, Int> = listOf(
        Pair("a", 1),
        Pair("b", null),
        Pair("c", 3),
        Pair("d", null)
)
.filter { it.first != null && it.second != null }
.associateBy({ it.first!! }, { it.second!! })

println(map)
```