# how to elegantly create a map with only non-null values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I rewrite this code without having to resort to a MutableMap and conversion to immutable map?

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> {
    val map = mutableMapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue)
    optionalValue?.let { map.put("key2", it) }
    return map.toMap()
}
```

My alternative solution isn't very nice either because it needs an unsafe cast:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> =
    mapOf(
        "key1" to mandatoryValue,
        "key2" to optionalValue
    ).filterValues { it != null } as Map<String, String>
```

What I am looking for is something in the lines of:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> =
    mapOf(
        "key1" to mandatoryValue,
        optionalValue?.let { "key2" to it }
    )
```

Comment: I think this is perfectly valid use of unchecked cast. Just add `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` to remove the warning and I think this is the best solution. Also, you can consider not hard-coding specific keys and values, but creating a generic function similar to `listOfNotNull()`, so you can use it e.g. as: `mapOfNotNullValues("key1" to mandatory, "key2" to optional)`.

Comment: See also [Collect to map skipping null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346846/collect-to-map-skipping-null-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toMap()` does not necessarily create an immutable map. It is only guaranteed to be read-only. The underlying class instance might be a MutableMap (which in the current implementation is true if it has more than one key). Therefore, `toMap()` in your first block of code is unnecessary. The MutableMap is automatically upcast to Map when you return it since you specified Map as the return type. So, you could have put

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> {
    val map = mutableMapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue)
    optionalValue?.let { map.put("key2", it) }
    return map
}
```

or

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> =
    mutableMapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue).apply {
        if (optionalValue != null) put("key2", optionalValue)
    }
```

To get the syntax you requested in your last example, you could create an overload of `mapOf` that accepts and filters null values:

```
fun <K, V> mapOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>?): Map<K, V> =
    mapOf(*pairs.filterNotNull().toTypedArray())
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going for your second solution, because it is the best fit with the rest of my code. It's pretty concise and clear, and not more generic than I need.

Comment: .toMap() is not redundant.

Comment: @Roman I’m not sure what you mean. `toMap()` creates a copy of the map, which is unnecessary here because the local MutableMap variable doesn’t escape the scope of the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yea, in this context it's really ok. In general a copy is just more safe. Thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can have your own extension function as follows and then use it to filter null values from a `Map`:

```kotlin
fun <K, V> Map<K, V?>.filterValuesNotNull() = 
    mapNotNull { (k, v) -> v?.let { k to v } }.toMap()
```

Comment: `associate { it }` could just be `toMap()`.

Comment: True and thanks for the hint. I will edit it to include the suggestion.

Comment: I guess mapNotNull() is an analogue of compactMap() in Swift

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using `MutableMap` - in fact your first solution (without the redundant `toMap()`) is already pretty elegant.  It's simpler and clearer than any immutable answer will be. Immutable operations come at the cost of additional object creations and copies, so unless you need the guarantees of immutability, it's best to use a `MutableMap` but only expose it via the `Map` interface, as you are already doing.

If you really wanted to do it immutably, you could do it like this:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> =
    mapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue) +
        (optionalValue?.let { mapOf("key2" to it) } ?: emptyMap())
```

Or equivalently if you prefer:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> =
    mapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue) +
        if (optionalValue != null) mapOf("key2" to optionalValue) else emptyMap()
```

Or:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> {
    val mandatoryMap = mapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue)
    return optionalValue?.let { mandatoryMap + ("key2" to optionalValue) } ?: mandatoryMap
}
```

Or:

```
fun createMap(mandatoryValue: String, optionalValue: String?): Map<String, String> {
    val mandatoryMap = mapOf("key1" to mandatoryValue)
    return if (optionalValue != null) mandatoryMap + ("key2" to optionalValue) else mandatoryMap
}
```

Comment: I don’t think the Kotlin standard library ever uses an immutable map implementation for maps with more than one entry, so these solutions only provide a read-only map that is *maybe* immutable. Going off my memory only though.

Comment: Right, but there are no mutable operations here, that's the point (well, the real point is: just use a `MutableMap`, it's simpler and clearer and more efficient).

Comment: Ok, I thought your mention of the needing the guarantees of immutability implied that your examples of “doing this immutably” guarantee immutability.

Comment: .toMap() is not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin 1.6

```
buildMap {
    put("key1", mandatoryValue)

    if (optionalValue != null)
        put("key2", optionalValue)
}
```

This creates a mutableMap under the sheets, but is quite elegant and readable <3